# Connect to host port 22 connection refused from Ubuntu to Kali via SSH in VMware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vmware-workstation

I have a PC running Kali Linux and a laptop running Ubuntu on VMWare. They are both on the same network. When I am trying to connect from Ubuntu to Kali via SSH I get the error port 22 connection refused.

However I can connect from the Kali to Ubuntu without any problem.

I tried already tried to allow port 22 connection on firewall and also accept all connection INPUT and OUTPUT in `iptables` but it didn’t work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. `sshd`service was not running on the Kali machine. 
I just started the service and it was working!